# calc() was removed for border when building css for angular 8

Tags: css, angular, sass

I was upgrading Angular 4 to Angular 8 and encountered a regression in my project.
The SASS below stopped giving the same output after the upgrade because somewhere in the building pipeline the calc() part in the css was removed.

It works if you use 12.5px directly which is a better way in this circumstance.

But my question is does anyone have any ideas why the calc() part was dropped or why it worked for the the css variable row?

SASS Input:

```css
    border-top: calc(25px / 2) solid transparent;
    border-bottom: calc(25px / 2) solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-left: calc(25px / 2) solid var(--accent-color);
```

CSS Output:

```css
    border-top: solid transparent;
    border-bottom: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-left: calc(25px / 2) solid var(--accent-color);
```

This works as expected:

```css
    border-top: 12.5px solid transparent; /* Input */
    border-top: 12.5px solid transparent; /* Output */
```

Comment: If there is something to do with Sass it should write some warnings or errors

Comment: There is one thing you can try - remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. Then call `npm i`

Comment: Also you could try to write `border-top: 25px / 2 solid transparent;` what supposedly will use sass function